# nodejs: Check if variable is readable stream

Tags: node.js

How i can check if a var is a readable stream in Nodejs?

Example:

```
function foo(streamobj){

   if(streamobj != readablestream){
       // Error: no writable stream
   }else{
      // So something with streamobj 
   }
}
```

I tried

```
if (!(streamobj instanceof stream.Readable)){
```

But than i get a ReferenceError: stream is not defined

Comment: Possible to get the solution provided here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is definitely that you haven't required `stream`. But. `instanceof` is not a good method to check if variable is a readable stream. Consider following cases:

- object can be old-style stream (instance of `stream.Stream`);
- object can be just emitter with `data` and `end` events;
- object can be instance of `Readable` from external module (https://github.com/isaacs/readable-stream);

The best way to go is [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Basically, if you are going to `pipe` stream, check if it has `pipe` method, if you are going to listen to events, check if stream has `on` method, etc.

Comment: thank you - i use if `(typeof streamobj.read != 'function'){`

Comment: you will also need `readable` event, so check `on` too. `read` is quite a common name

Comment: just the same, `typeof streamobj.on === 'function'`

Comment: I know this is old but... By now, readable-stream library is an standard, in fact is maintained by the node's developer team and its purpose is to maintain consistency within node versions. With that said, you should always use readable stream module if you want to guarantee that your project will work between node versions, also this library always returns the core Stream object, so there is no need for doing duck typing. The correct answer is using instanceof

Answer (score 12):

It seems that you forgot to require the stream core module.

```
var stream = require('stream');

// somewhere in the file
if (!(streamobj instanceof stream.Readable)) {
    // Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [is-stream](https://npmjs.org/package/is-stream) package for that:

```js
var isStream = require('is-stream');
if (isStream.readable(myStream)) {
  do();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't tell you if its a readable stream nor should you be requiring in yet another npm package to check something simple inherent the the language ```maybeStream instanceof require('stream').Stream === aBoolean```

Comment: It does. Why we should not be requiring a package? I think the opposite − streams are not part of the language, and relying on a package for common operations is better alternative to writing a chunk of code every and other project.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do:

```
var stream = require('stream');
```

The function could be something like:

```
function isReadableStream(obj) {
  return obj instanceof stream.Stream &&
    typeof (obj._read === 'function') &&
    typeof (obj._readableState === 'object');
}

console.log(isReadableStream(fs.createReadStream('car.jpg'))); // true
console.log(isReadableStream({}))); // false
console.log(isReadableStream(''))); // false
```